# undefined method `remove_previously_stored_files_after_update' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000d3f7778> carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm working with image upload with rails 4 but I'm having problem to make it work.

```
undefined method `remove_previously_stored_files_after_update' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000d3f7778>
```

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Below is the **full trace:**

> carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:233:in
>   `store_previous_model_for_image' activesupport (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:430:in`block in make_lambda'
>   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:162:in `call'
>   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:162:in`block in
>   halting' activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in
>   `call' activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in`
>   block in call' activesupport (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in `each' activesupport (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in`call' activesupport (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks' activerecord
>   (4.2.3) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:310:in`_update_record'
>   activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:70:in
>   `_update_record' activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/persistence.rb:504:in`create_or_update'
>   activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in
>   create_or_update' activesupport (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in`call' activesupport (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call' activesupport (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in`block (2 levels) in compile'
>   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
>   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in`call'
>   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in
>   `run_callbacks' activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in`create_or_update' activerecord
>   (4.2.3) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:120:in `save' activerecord
>   (4.2.3) lib/active_record/validations.rb:37:in`save' activerecord
>   (4.2.3) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
>   activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in`block
>   (2 levels) in save' activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in
>   with_transaction_returning_status' activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in`
>   transaction' activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction' activerecord
>   (4.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in`
>   with_transaction_returning_status' activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block in save' activerecord
>   (4.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in`
>   rollback_active_record_state!' activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save' activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/persistence.rb:252:in`block in update' activerecord
>   (4.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in
>   with_transaction_returning_status' activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in`
>   block in transaction' activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in
>   `within_new_transaction' activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in`
>   transaction' activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction' activerecord
>   (4.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in`
>   with_transaction_returning_status' activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/persistence.rb:250:in `update'
>   app/controllers/front/ads_controller.rb:38:in`update' actionpack
>   (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in
>   `send_action' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in`process_action' actionpack
>   (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in`block in process_action'
>   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
>   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in`call'
>   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2
>   levels) in compile' activesupport (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in`call' activesupport (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call' activesupport (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in`run_callbacks' actionpack
>   (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in`
>   process_action' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in
>   process_action' activesupport (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`block in instrument'
>   activesupport (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
>   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`
>   instrument' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in`process_action'
>   activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in`process' actionview (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in`dispatch' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in`block in
>   action' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call' actionpack
>   (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in
>   `serve' actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in`
>   block in serve' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in`serve' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in`call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/head.rb:13:in`call' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in`
>   call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call' actionpack
>   (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
>   activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in`call'
>   activerecord (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in
>   `call' activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in`
>   call' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
>   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in`
>   run_callbacks' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call' actionpack
>   (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in
>   `call' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
>   web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
>   railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app' railties
>   (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call' activesupport
>   (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`
>   tagged' activesupport (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged' railties (4.2.3)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in`call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call' activesupport (4.2.3)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in`
>   call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call' actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in`call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call' railties (4.2.3)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in`call' railties (4.2.3)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in`service'
>   C:/ruby/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in
>   `service'
>   C:/ruby/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
>   C:/ruby/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in
>   start_thread'

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the complete error stacktrace and the related models?